# Genetic Algorithm - Best crossover operator for a weights assignment

Tags: genetic-algorithm

According to your experience, what is the best crossover operator for weights assignment problem.
In particular, I am facing a constraint that force to be 1 the sum of the all weights. Currently, I am using the uniform crossover operator and then I divide all the parameters by the sum to get 1. The crossover works, but I am not sure that in this way I can save the good part of my solution and go to converge to a better solution.
Do you have any suggestion? No problem, if I need to build a custom operator.

Answer (score 2):

If your initial population is made up of feasible individuals you could try a [differential evolution](http://www1.icsi.berkeley.edu/~storn/code.html)-like approach.

The recombination operator needs three (random) vectors and adds the weighted difference between two population vectors to a third vector:

```
offspring = A + f (B - C)
```

You could try a fixed weighting factor `f` in the [0.6 ; 2.0] range or experimenting selecting `f` randomly for each generation or for each difference vector (a technique called *dither*, which should improve convergence behaviour significantly, especially for noisy objective functions).

This should work quite well since the offspring will automatically be feasible.

Special care should be taken to avoid premature convergence (e.g. some niching algorithm).

EDIT

With uniform crossover you are exploring the entire n-dimensional space, while the above recombination limits individuals to a subspace `H` (the hyperplane Σ<sub>i</sub> w<sub>i</sub> = 1, where w<sub>i</sub> are the weights) of the original search space.

Reading the question I assumed that the sum-of-the-weights was the only constraint. Since there are other constraints, it's not true that the offspring is automatically feasible.

Anyway any feasible solution must be on `H`:

If A = (a<sub>1</sub>, a<sub>2</sub>, ... a<sub>n</sub>), B = (b<sub>1</sub>, ... b<sub>n</sub>), C = (c<sub>1</sub>, ... c<sub>n</sub>) are feasible:

- Σ<sub>i</sub> a<sub>i</sub> = 1
- Σ<sub>i</sub> b<sub>i</sub> = 1
- Σ<sub>i</sub> c<sub>i</sub> = 1

so

Σ<sub>i</sub> (a<sub>i</sub> + f (b<sub>i</sub> - c<sub>i</sub>)) = 
Σ<sub>i</sub> a<sub>i</sub> + f (Σ<sub>i</sub> b<sub>i</sub> - Σ<sub>i</sub> c<sub>i</sub>) = 
1 + f (1 - 1) = 1

The offspring is on the `H` hyperplane.

Now depending on the number / type of additional constraints you could modify the proposed recombination operator or try something based on a penalty function.

EDIT2

You could determine analytically the "valid" range of `f`, but probably something like this is enough:

```
f = random(0.6, 2.0);

double trial[] = {f, f/2, f/4, -f, -f/2, -f/4, 0};

i = 0;
do
{
  offspring = A +  trial[i] * (B - C);
  i = i + 1;
} while (unfeasible(offspring));

return offspring;
```

This is just a idea, I'm not sure how it works.

Comment: First of all, thank you for your help. So you would suggest a DE approach. Can you explain me why you think it should work better than a simple uniform crossover?
And then, yes, my population consists of feasible individuals, but I do not understand why following this approach offsprings should be automatically feasible. Actually, I could get also negative values, which are forbidden in my case, but anyway the sum is not always 1. Maybe I did not understand well.

Comment: Sorry, you are right! Sure I made some mistake before! :P
It is a pity I can not use that system. Unfortunately, negative weights are forbidden and I have no other constraints. Do you think exits a way to fix it? I could choose a random value of F for each vector that satisfy the constraint, but I think it could take a lot of time, does it not?
I heard about penalty functions, but I have no idea how they can help me with my problem.

Comment: With a penalty function you replace a constrained optimization problem with an unconstrained problem formed by adding a term, called a penalty function, to the original objective function. The penalty consists of a parameter multiplied by a measure of violation of the constraints. You could take a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penalty_method

Comment: About EDIT2, that was exactly what I meant.
What is the advantage of using a penalty function in a constrained problem? I mean, I suspect it takes more time to converge. Am I wrong?